# Tiny C Compiler arm

Tags: c, arm, tcc

I would like to compile and run C code at runtime for iOS and Android. Can Tiny C Compiler run on arm64 and armv7? If that's possible, how do I set up the XCode and android project to run Tiny C Compiler?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It just won't work. Compiling code for iOS/Android involve lots of tools, and TCC just does not support that.
Plus, it is forbidden by Apple to do so.

There is many steps in the building of an app, involving linking with the SDK, making a bundle, signing the code, ...

Comment: Downvoted because this is simply wrong. It is possible to compile pure C on Android and many apps allow you to do this. Additionally with rooted phones you can install GCC and compile and run software via a terminal. Accessing advanced graphics and such without the SDK is probably troublesome though.

Comment: It is complex to generate a app for iOS or Android w/o the toolchain, however run some some code inside a standard-maid app is other story.